# Google Maps Click Anything BUT RichMarker Listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

When I click the [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) an infobox opens correctly. When I click the map I want the infobox to close.

This opens the infobox correctly:

```
var itm = document.getElementById("marker-div").cloneNode(true);

marker = new RichMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(49, 120),
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    shadow: '',
    content: itm
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infobox.setContent('<div>Hi there</div>');      //load infobox content...
    infobox.open(map, this);                        //open infobox...
});
```

I do not know how to close the infobox on map click. If I include this listener, the infobox never opens because the close function fires on every click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

    infobox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cancel the bubbling of the marker-click:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      infobox.setContent('<div>Hi there</div>');      //load infobox content...
      infobox.open(map, this);                        //open infobox...
    });
```